# Python: Define subgroup of data with multiple conditions

Tags: python

I have a table with several dummy variables

[image]

I would now like to create a subgroup where I list the winpercent values of those rows where fruity=1 and hard=0. My first attempt was this one but it was unsuccesful:

```
df6=full_data[full_data['fruity'&'hard']==['1'&'0'].iloc[:,-1]
```

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please write the conditions one by one separated by the '&' operator:

```
full_data.loc[(full_data['fruity'] == 1) &
          (full_data['hard'] == 0), 'winpercent']
```

You can also query it:

```
full_data.query("fruity == 1 and hard == 0", inplace=False)['winpercent']
```

Comment: It says TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'str' with me. Any idea why?

Comment: Sorry my bad. Please see the edited answer. Also see full_data.dtypes. It is important to ensure that the condition uses the same dtype as the column's